# Compress a string using GZip, the string is not shorter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I used the following code to compress a string, but the string is not shorter.  Can you explain why?

```
  private string Compress(string str)
        {
            try
            {
                String returnValue;
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                    {
                        zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.ASCII))
                        {
                            returnValue = sReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }

                }
                return returnValue;                
            }
            catch
            {
                return str;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the input, what is the output? Did you land in the catch block by any chance? Did you debug it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `catch` block to see if your code is silently failing? In general, never write `catch { }` -- even `catch (Exception ex) { log(ex) }` is marginally better, although usually still too broad.

Comment: Why are you reading the contents of the memory stream (which is binary) back as if it were an ASCII string? This will mangle the output beyond recovery.

Comment: Your immediate problem is that you are trying to read the contents of the buffer while the `GZipStream` isn't flushed yet -- move the innermost `using` block one level higher to fix that. But this will still not fix the issue that your code doesn't achieve what you're really after, so what is it that you're really after?

Comment: Are you testing with short input strings? Zip adds a preamble (lookup table) which can make short input strings even longer once 'compressed'. Test with a much longer input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring issues in the code - there are multiple possible scenarios when this can happen.

Simplified explanation of compression algorithm - compression is based on the fact that data you are trying to compress contain redundant values - patterns which can be recognized by the compression algorithm and can be "shortened" by expressing the redundant values more concisely.

Some scenarios when the compressed result can be larger then the input:

1) Input is too short - compression algorithms have some data overhead and considering the short input, it is unable to compress it effectively. So you have some data overhead from the compression mechanism + original data.

2) Input is already compressed - again, compression algorithms have some data overhead and when is the input already compressed - it is unable to compress it effectively.

3) Input is too random - considering the input is generated by some random generator, the compression algorithm is unable to compress it effectively - no patterns can be recognized.